# How to parse letter numerical codes with jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

My problem is simple, but I can't find a way to fix it. I hope to get some help here. Since I had problems with language support on my page, I was forced to use letter codes. E.g. `&#1040; &#1041;` - Russian letters А and Б. Because I don't have that much of Russian content on the page, I didn't bother to search for alternative way. But I stuck with this problem:

```
        function updateTips( t ) {
            tips
                .text( t )
                .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
            setTimeout(function() {
                tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
            }, 500 );
        }
        function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
            if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
                o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
                //here is my problem situated
                updateTips( "&#1044;&#1083;&#1080;&#1085;&#1072; " + n + " &#1076;&#1086;&#1083;&#1078;&#1085;&#1072; &#1073;&#1099;&#1090;&#1100; &#1084;&#1091;&#1078;&#1076;&#1091; " + min + " &#1080; " + max + "." );
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
            if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
                o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
                updateTips( n );
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

When the code is executed, the output isn't the one I wish to see. As the output I see same `"&#1044;&#1083;&#1080;&#1085;&#1072;...."` and it supposed to show letters, which belong to those codes. Any advise or alternative way for fixing this issue would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Somewhat of a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding  Answer you are looking for with a clean implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `function updateTips( t )`, change `.text` to `.html`.

This should fix it.

### Edit:

The **reason** for this is because the point of `.text()` is explicitly to *not* interpret whatever is in the string.  It's meant for things like XML, where you need the string exactly as it was passed.

Comment: It was so obvious xD I think I need to sleep more. Thank you very much! Problem solved.